# Automata based alternative to re2

Tags: c++, regex, expression, re2

I am needing to implement regular expressions in a C++ program I am writing, and I wanted to use re2 but I could not compile it on windows. Does anyone know of another regular expression library or whatever it's called that compiles easily on windows and isn't a "backtracking" regex engine, but an automata-theory based one (whatever that means) like re2 is?

Or just figuring out how to compile re2 on windows would be perfect.

Comment: What compilation problems were you having?

Comment: Things not being defined, mainly. There was a billion errors. I can paste all of them into codepad if it would help.

Comment: I am author of the port to Windows http://code.google.com/p/re2win/ just be careful with automatic conversion to integer (do the conversion yourself).

Comment: Know that Google's re2 is **slow** for capturing parenthesis, slower than PCRE. Where re2 really shines is keeping its stack usage small and matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are part of the TR1 standard, so chances are you already have a `<tr1/regex>` header that [contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382.aspx) a `std::tr1::regex` class and related functions.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable at all in this stuff, is that as fast as re2?

Comment: And I'm using Microsoft Visual C++, and I don't seem to have a <tr1/regex> file.

Comment: Please note that `tr1/regex` as found in VC9 SP1 is slow. VC10 is also 20 times slower than boost in some common usages! So `boost::regex` is probably better than the one that comes with your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://www.complang.org/ragel/

It's an external DSL so not technically C++. However as it generates
pure C++ / C from the regular expressions it should be much faster than
anything that is built at runtime./

For example.

```
action dgt      { printf("DGT: %c\n", fc); }
action dec      { printf("DEC: .\n"); }
action exp      { printf("EXP: %c\n", fc); }
action exp_sign { printf("SGN: %c\n", fc); }
action number   { /*NUMBER*/ }

number = (
    [0-9]+ $dgt ( '.' @dec [0-9]+ $dgt )?
    ( [eE] ( [+\-] $exp_sign )? [0-9]+ $exp )?
) %number;

main := ( number '\n' )*;
```

get's compiled down to

```
st0:
    if ( ++p == pe )
        goto out0;
    if ( 48 <= (*p) && (*p) <= 57 )
        goto tr0;
    goto st_err;
tr0:
    { printf("DGT: %c\n", (*p)); }
st1:
    if ( ++p == pe )
        goto out1;
    switch ( (*p) ) {
        case 10: goto tr5;
        case 46: goto tr7;
        case 69: goto st4;
        case 101: goto st4;
    }
    if ( 48 <= (*p) && (*p) <= 57 )
        goto tr0;
    goto st_err;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a port of RE2 for Windows at http://code.google.com/p/re2win/ . It builds with lots of warnings, no errors.